# Передача переменной get на другую страницу

Tags: php, ajax, get

Доброго времени суток.
Вопрос в чем собственно, не получается реализовать статью.
Есть главная страница, на ней как бы плитки с изображением и коротким описанием, при нажатии на одну из них появляется div (pop-up) и в нем выводится более конкретная информация плитки на которую вы нажали, все это работает без обновления страницы. У меня просто не выводит вообще ничего с select.php!

index.php

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#popup1").hide();

    var nav, content;

    nav = $('.item');
    content = $('.o-post');

    nav.find('a').on('click', function(e) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        history.pushState(null, null, href);

        $("#popup1").show();  

        e.preventDefault();

        var data = { id: id };
        var res = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax({
            url: "select.php", 
            type: "GET",
            data: { data: res },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){               
                content.html(response);
            }
        });  
    });

    $("#hide-post").click(function() {        
        $("#popup1").hide();
    });
});
</script>
        <div class="b-popup" id="popup1">
            <div class="b-popup-content">
            <img src="./icons/close.png" id="hide-post" style="cursor: pointer; float: right;">
                <div class="o-post"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

select.php

```
    <?php
include('connect.php');

$post_sql = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='$_GET[id]'");
while($post_row = mysqli_fetch_array($post_sql)) {
        echo '<img src="./img/user_images/'.$post_row['image'].'" width="500px" id="image-post"><p>'.$post_row['description'].'</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Прежде чем писать цикл `while` надо убедиться, что что-то вообще  из базы подтянулось ли.............к тому же, должен вернуться `json` судя по настройке `ajax`, а вы выпихиваете `html` ................ А еще как только одна строка вывелась через `echo` она отсылается ответом в аякс и всё, остальные итерации не отработают, вывод:  нужно в начале сложить всё в переменную и только её потом отдавать  как ответ

Comment: @АлексейШиманский там с ajax проблемы скорее всего, потому что select.php работал, я поменял content.html(response) на content.json(response), но оно все равно не работает

Comment: Потому что ты не понимаешь, что делаешь. Причем тут непонятный content.json? С какого потолка он взялся?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я только учусь, и много чего не понимаю, если знаешь как сделать чтобы работало, помоги)

Comment: в моём первом комментарии собственно всё написано уже. осталось только это применить.... либо `dataType: "html",` должен быть либо `echo json_decode(YOUR_CONTENT)` ......поищи что такое `dataType` и что он значит например тут http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81#.D0.9F.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80_dataType ..........ну и другие пункты которые я описал - проверяй/выполняй

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а как засунуть в `data` `$_GET['id']` и передать его в `select.php`, если стоит `dataType: html` ?

Comment: Еще раз повторю: почитай что такое `dataType` и что он означает